# Angular + Express.js app in Electron doesn't starts

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, electron

I have successfully managed to build MEAN App. Now i want that app to run inside electron. The following command is working on web browser

```
"electron-build": "ng build && node ./bin/www"
```

But when i tried this code

```
"electron-build": "ng build && electron . && node ./bin/www"
```

The build is successful and the app runs in electron but the server is not running & when i quit the electron app from GUI i got the successful connection log in console.

Now when i tried this code

```
"electron-build": "ng build && node ./bin/www && electron ."
```

The server starts successfully but the electron app doesn't rendered.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Chetan Yup. The solution require to use this package https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron and also check this issue regarding express.js integration https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/issues/226

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that two process (node ./bin/www and electron.) can't be execute in same Thread.

You can do some like that

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const path = require('path');

function createWindow () {
    win2 = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

    win2.loadURL(
    path.join('file://', __dirname, '/index.html')
    );    
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

And in index.html add the  tag with you server.js or app.js (file with code of node/express). Like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Simple Mouse Control - Server</title>

        <script src="server.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        Hola
    </body>
</html>
```

And finally:

```
"electron-build": "ng build && electron ."
```